# Excel VBA: How to remove cell fill colour whenever a string is entered into the cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new, so bear with me. I have a shared excel file that multiple users can read/write. It comes with a section where a user can acknowledge they've read the worksheet  using this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I9:J359")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Cancel = True
        If Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 35
        Else
           If Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 35 Then Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End If
    End If
    End Sub
```

Users would just double click to colour their names in. Users can also input new messages into the worksheet. Therein lies the problem of new 'messages' being input with names coloured in showing they have read the message when they have not.

Is there a code that would 'uncolour' the users list when a new message is entered - meaning user would know there are new inputs and would need to acknowledge the latest update in the worksheet.

Comment: Apparently `Range("I9:J359").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone`?

Comment: Where are the data, the user name, the old message, and the new message? When should what be (un)colored? Add more accurate information to your post.